# Why a struct member is not visible to my function?

Tags: solidity, remix, struct

The very last function of the code `makeBet()` is throwing an error when I want to deploy it on Remix. The error says that *member `status` is not found or not visible* when calling `Game.status`. That is very odd for me, as the struct Game clearly has member status defined in it as `enum` state. Where did I go wrong?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4

contract Bet {
    
    address payable owner;

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    // Bet status
    enum BetStatus { LONG, SHORT, NGMI }

    //the game structure
    struct Game {
      uint256 betPrice;
      uint256 betAmount;
      BetStatus status;
      address maker;
      address taker;
      string deadline;
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => Game) public games;
    Game[] public activeGames;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
    }

    receive() external payable {
    }

     /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
     */
    constructor() public payable {
      priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(address(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331));
    }

    function getThePrice() public view returns (int) {
      (
        uint80 roundID,
        int price,
        uint startedAt,
        uint timeStamp,
        uint80 answeredInRound
      ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();

      return price;
    }

    function makeBet(uint _guess, string memory deadline) public payable {
      Game(msg.value, _guess, BetStatus(0), msg.sender, address(0), deadline);
      uint current_price = uint(getThePrice());

      if (_guess > current_price) {
        Game.status = BetStatus.LONG;
      } else if (_guess < current_price) {
        Game.status = BetStatus.SHORT;
      } else {
        Game.status = BetStatus.NGMI;
      }
}

function takeBet() public payable {
      //requires the taker to make the same bet amount
      
      require(msg.value == Games.betAmount);
      Game.taker = msg.sender;
    }

    function getBetOutcome() public payable {
      // TODO: remove game from activeGames map here

      uint current_price = uint(getThePrice());
      if (Game.status == BetStatus.LONG && current_price >= Game.betPrice) {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = Game.maker.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
      } else if (Game.status == BetStatus.SHORT && current_price <= Game.betPrice) {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = Game.maker.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
      } else {
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = Game.taker.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Game` is a type. You have defined the type as a struct.

In the `makeBet()` function you have not created a local variable of type `Game`. What you're doing is trying to assign a value to a type definition, not a variable.

You need something along the lines of:

```
function makeBet(uint _guess, string memory deadline) public payable {
  Game memory newGame = Game(msg.value, _guess, BetStatus(0), msg.sender, address(0), deadline);
  uint current_price = uint(getThePrice());

  if (_guess > current_price) {
    newGame.status = BetStatus.LONG;
  } else if (_guess < current_price) {
    newGame.status = BetStatus.SHORT;
  } else {
    newGame.status = BetStatus.NGMI;
  }

  activeGames.push(newGame);
}
```

Alternatively, you could push the new struct directly without creating a convenience variable:

```
function makeBet(uint _guess, string memory deadline) public payable {  
  BetStatus newStatus;
  uint current_price = uint(getThePrice());

  if (_guess > current_price) {
    newStatus = BetStatus.LONG;
  } else if (_guess < current_price) {
    newStatus = BetStatus.SHORT;
  } else {
    newStatus = BetStatus.NGMI;
  }

  activeGames.push(Game({
    betPrice: msg.value, 
    betAmount: _guess, 
    status: newStatus, 
    maker: msg.sender, 
    taker: address(0), 
    deadline: deadline}));
}
```

Comment: And what kind of an identifier could I assign to Game then? Because ```activeGames.push(newGame);``` throws an error of *newGame - Undeclared identifier*

Comment: Already in the very beginning I tried assigning a local variable ```game = Game(msg.value, _guess, BetStatus(0), msg.sender, address(0), deadline);``` but couldn't figure out what kind of an identifier could a *struct* use, as it is a collection of different types.

Comment: _"throws an error of newGame - Undeclared identifier"_ <- You mean the first example doesn't compile?

Comment: Okay, it compiles for me (Solidity v0.8.4). Can you copy+paste the whole function and replace the one in your code, and try again?

Comment: Oki doki, once copy pasted it works fine. However, the next functions need to follow the same logic, or they throw the same error. I updated the original post to add ```takeBet()``` and ```getBetOutcome()``` functions. Could you please tell me what kind of an identifier a struct could use so I can solve these problems and compile? Thank you so much for your help, you already helped a lot.

Comment: For both of those functions you'll need to know the index of the bet in the `activeGames[]` array. Then you can create a local variable which points to that bet: `Game storage activeBet = activeGames[index];`. (Then you can do the rest of the function logic.)

Comment: No problem - happy to help :-)